# Need help renaming certain files in a directory Python

Tags: python

I am trying to rename .docx and .doc files to .txt files. I am a newbie. Here is the code.

```
try:
    files = os.listdir(src)
    for fileName in list_files :
        if os.path.splitext(fileName)[1].lower() in ['.docx', '.doc'] :
            print(fileName)
            #if file[0].lower() in ['a','b','c'] :
            #    os.rename(src, fileName.rename(".txt"))
            #    break
```

Comment: Indent your code please!

Answer (score 1):

Almost there!

```
for file in os.listdir(src):
    filename,ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    if ext.lower() in ['.docx','.doc']:
        os.rename(file,filename+".txt")
```

Better is probably:

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob("*.doc*"):
    os.rename(file,"{}.txt".format(os.path.splitext(file)[0]))
```

Comment: @user3597409 without more information no one can help you. "This didn't work" can range from "It ran and completed but didn't rename files" to "It failed with an error" to "My computer exploded when I ran this script" to "This summoned the elder god Cthulu, God save us all!"